# RuntimeWarning: Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, warnings

I'm trying to learn how machine learning works in Python using Keras. To learn this I use websites and tutorials. My problem is: even if I exactly copy their code, I still get a warning and it runs very slow. It can take minutes to run a few epochs and every few epochs I get this warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py", line 95
    % (hook_name, delta_t_median), RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (0.115399). Check your callbacks.
```

My code:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

dataset = loadtxt('data_m3_2.csv', delimiter=',')
#8 input variables (X). 1 output variable, 0 or 1 (y)
X = dataset[:,0:8] #columns 0 to 7 ??
y = dataset[:,8]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu')) #defines input layer and first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(8,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) #sigmoid to ensure output between 0 and 1

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=3, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply install CUDA (if you have a GPU) and use it? If you have an AMD GPU look up "PLiadML". It will decrease compute time drastically...

Comment: Thanks 'neel g'! I'm gonna try that!